# Sorting algorithm efficiency comparison

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I was playing around with simple sorting algorithms to become more familiar with them, and tried to create insertion sort from the description of the algorithm rather than the pseudocode. I made an algorithm that worked and that I thought fitted the description:

```
import random
nums = []
for i in range(10000):
    nums.append(random.randrange(0, 1000))

def getSortedIndexForEle(ele, sorted):
    for i in range(0, len(sorted)):
        if ele < sorted[i]:
            return i
    return len(sorted)

def sort(lst):
    sorted = []
    for ele in lst:
        sorted.insert(getSortedIndexForEle(ele, sorted), ele)
    return sorted

print(sort(nums))
```

However the code did not match the algorithm compisition wise (but still produced the correct result) so I had another attempt:

```
import random
nums = []
for i in range(10000):
    nums.append(random.randrange(0, 1000))

def sort(lst):
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        ele = lst[i]
        j = i - 1
        for k in range(j, -2, -1):
            if ele >= lst[k]:
                break
            lst[k + 1] = lst[k]
        lst[k + 1] = ele


sort(nums)
print(nums)
```

I believe this one is correct, and I compared it to the pseudocode and it does effectively the same thing.

My question is the first algorithm that I made, which did not fit the algorithm, executes in around half the time of the actual thing on my machine (using a list of length 10000, every element a random number). How can this be possible?  Is my second algorithm not correct? I even tried a python example of the algorithm and that also took longer than my first one...

Comment: I can make my code arbitrarily fast if it doesn't have to produce the correkt result :-) For example `#define rand(x) 42`.

Comment: It did produce the correct result though, the code itself did not match the algorithm. Sorry, I should have been clearer.

Comment: Can you explain `range(j, -2, -1)`? Not familiar with python.

Comment: First and second parameters are the start and end values of the range (start value is included in the range while the end value is excluded) and the third parameter is whether the loop should increment or decrement (1 for increment and -1 for decerement).

Comment: Whoops just realized that last comment was misleading, the third parameter is actually the step, which is being used to decrement in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one sorts in-place, the first one doesn't.

In the second algorithm, you insert each element in the original array and every element after that has to be shifted to accommodate it. Time complexity is O(n2) but it only requires constant O(1) extra memory.

In the first one, you insert an element in separate array and only the larger elements that have already been sorted have to be shifted. So time complexity is somewhere between O(n) and O(n2) but it requires O(n) extra memory.

Comment: Ahhh so is it because the insertion algorithm aims to have as little overhead/memory usage as possible, it takes longer so it can achieve the O(1) memory usage by the algorithm itself (using in-place)?

Comment: Yeah, insertion sort is generally in place (though not *neccesarily*), but usually yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, that is exactly what I wanted to know :) I learn a lot better when I understand these small things!

Answer (score 0):

Heres an insertion sort off top of my head (sorry it's in pseudo code, but it should give you a basic idea of how it works).

```
for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
    for (int insertion = index; insertion > 0 && array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1]; --insertion) {
        swap(array[insertion], array[insertion - 1];
    } 
}
```

Think about it this way, we have two moving cursors:

```
for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++)
```

The job of this one is to slide all the way to the end of the collection (notice we start at the second item, not the first!).

Then we have this one:

```
for (int insertion = index - 1; array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1] && insertion > 0; --insertion)
```

This one is long so I'll take it apart:

```
for (int insertion = index; ...; --insertion)
```

This means that our comparison point starts at wherever `index` points, and moves *backwards* after every iteration. (Hmm, Why backwards?)

```
for (; insertion > 0 && array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1];)
```

as we slide backwards we need to make two comparisons:

(1) Is the insertion index greater than zero? Obviously if we reach the 'base' of the collection, then we're obviously done. No need to continue and we let `index` move forward one step.

(2) Is the item pointed to by `insertion` less than the item before it? That's not right, we need to swap those. In fact, we'll continue swapping pairs of items backwards until everything to the left of `index` is sorted.

Basically this combination of for statements stays:

(1) Put `index` at 1, then sort everything to the left of it. There are only two items [0] and [1], so that's easy.

(2) Move index forward, now there are three items. Sort [0], [1], and [2]. Keep moving index forward one by one, and sorting the left-hand-side as we progress.

(3) We 'sort' by ensuring that the new item introduced by moving `index` forward gets slid backwards into place. That's the point of `array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1]`. In other words, slide newly introduced items backwards until they sit into place.

(4) Since the left hand side is always sorted by definition, all we need to do after incrementing `index` is to make sure to move the new item into place.

Increment, then slide the new item into place. Rinse and repeat.

Visually:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

Zero is out of place, so when `index = 4`, `insertion = 4` as well. Then we start comparing backwards.

Is array[4] < array [4 - 1]? Yes, 0 < 4, so we swap:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
```

Again, is array[3] < array[3 - 1]? Yes, 0 < 3 swap:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
```

Again and again until we move the `0` to the first position because that that point array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1] will be false.

Basically all you're doing is making sure the left hand side of `index` has no items such that array[insertion] < array[insertion - 1]. If that's true for 2 elements, then we check for three, and then for four etc.

Interestingly we don't need to check the entire left side each time, because once it's sorted, the only element that can be out of place is the *NEW* element introduced by incrementing `index`. That is, if we add a new item, *ONLY* that item can be out of place, so once we move that one into place, by definition the entire left side is sorted!

Comment: Thanks for you help codes :) I get the hang of the algorithm now, I was more confused about how my random algorithm was faster, which was because i was sacrificing space complexity for speed.